# SQL Combine two rows into one

Tags: sql

I'm trying with SQL to combine two rows into one in SQL with a new ID number

```
ID  Amount
------------
1   100
2   200
3   300
4   400
5   500
6   600
```

into

```
ID  Amount
-------------
1   100
2   200
101 700
5   500
6   600
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: On what basis?  Are you after a query or a data update?

Comment: Do you means **delete** two **known** rows, and **insert** one `sum` row with new `id`? Or just select the expected result from table?

Comment: Please specify the data you are hoping to generate, as your question contains insufficient information to answer

Answer (score 0):

Check out [SQL Procedures](http://www.mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-stored-procedure-update-example/). I'm not sure about your goals but I think what you need is to define a SQL Procedure. It's been I while since I did that, but it should go like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE combine(
           ID1 IN <TABLE_NAME>.ID%TYPE,
           ID2 IN <TABLE_NAME>.ID%TYPE,
           NEWID IN <TABLE_NAME>.ID%TYPE)
    IS
    BEGIN

        INSERT INTO <TABLE_NAME> (ID, Amount) VALUES(NEWID, ((SELECT Amount FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE ID=ID1) + (SELECT Amount FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE ID=ID2)));
        DELETE FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE ID = ID1;
        DELETE FROM <TABLE_NAME> WHERE ID = ID2;

    COMMIT;

END;
/
```

To get the state as described by you, you can call the routine by

```
combine(4, 5, 101);
```